# Issues with this function

Tags: c++

I was told there is an issue with this function, however after doing research and trying to use it myself, I can't seem to find what is wrong with it. Was someone just trying to mess with me?

```
std::string foo() throw()
{
    std::string s("hello world");
    return s;
}
```

Comment: What were you told was wrong...? There is a possibility of return value optimization and copy elision, but that is all I see.

Comment: @callyalater This and `throw` is considered bad practice by many, but otherwise this is completely fine,

Comment: Other than `throw()` being deprecated, I can't see anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your compiler settings, `std::string` may throw from its constructor if allocation of the backing memory for the string contents fails. This would violate the `throw()` clause that you put.

Otherwise, the code is fine, though of course it can be shortened:

```
std::string foo()
{
    return "hello world";
}
```

Comment: That is what I thought but my professor kept hinting that there was something wrong with it. Thank you

Comment: If anything, you'd want the function to indicate it is returning a `const` value, with this method, since trying to modify this `"hello world"` will not be fun.

Comment: @user: But it's not returning a const object. `std::string` creates a new, fully modifiable string containing a copy of the constant string. Every `std::string` fully contains its contents in a buffer on the heap that it owns; no `std::string` references memory owned by anyone else, including other `std::string`s (at least, it's not allowed to appear to do so -- some STL implementations do have a copy-on-write `std::string`, but it amounts to the same thing).

Comment: Ah, you're correct, @Cameron. I thought it was just returning a string literal, but seems C++ is smart enough to wrap it in a proper std::string before returning.

Comment: @user3470630 the return type is `std::string`   ; the expression after `return` is taken as an initializer for an object whose type is the return type

Comment: @RyanNewman the "something wrong" is (a) `std::string`'s constructor may throw, causing undefined behaviour due to the presence of `throw()`,  and (b) `throw()` is nowdays considered bad practice